# Ajax post file identical codes but different request headers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having problems with understanding how jQuery create headers for ajax post. I have two identical codes on different domains. When I upload image from first domain I get this

```
dAccept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:sl-SI,sl;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:255066
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5LGqeDQ41hDSN3D8
Cookie:__utma=101786774.1930543898.1315154165.1331048004.1331409652.146; __utmz=101786774.1315154165.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=av1jlmchvb75tfvreq9fg6o6j1
Host:domain1.local
Origin:http://domain1.local
Referer:http://domain1.local/upload
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpReques
```

On domain1 image upload works. However on domain2 we got different resoults

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:sl-SI,sl;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:255066
Content-Type:false
Cookie:PHPSESSID=l8216r89no29ht2e2r5083b4j6
Host:domain2.local
Origin:http://domain2.local
Referer:http://domain2.local/upload
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Why is there content-type false? Any ideas?

Comment: I found a MSDN reference to Read-Only content http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434692.aspx but that is the first time I came across Content-Type: false plus it looks like you are using PHP. Does your app apply some security model logic for read/write access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted apache and everything works fine. So no answer here.